# Cut Java Development Kit using AspectJ

Tags: java, aspectj

I want cut the Java Development Kit(JDK) classes using AspectJ. Is it possible? And does someone have an example? The tools that I use are Eclipse and AspectJ plugin.

Comment: In 95% of all cases what users want to achieve is possible without weaving into JDK classes. I know how to do it but urge you to avoid it if you can. Please edit your question and describe what you want to do. Please also provide some sample code we can discuss. I want to avoid making this a phisosophical discussion. StackOverflow is not a forum, it is a Q/A site about software development.

Comment: The question looks fair to me. There shouldn't be a restriction when asking something which is not a best practice. By the way, what if the case is within 5%?